# The output of 'ulimit -n' is different between the jumper terminal and the server mahcine

Tags: jupyter-lab, ulimit

When i executes 'ulimit -n' in the server machine, i get a below one.

```
$ ulimit -n
1048576
```

But i executes 'ulimit -n' in the jupyter terminal, i get a below one.

```
$ ulimit -n
4096
```

Why the outputs are not same? I'm very confused.
I use a conda and doubt it as first. but when i execute 'ulimit -n' in the activated conda environment, i got a same one i got from the server mahcine.

I inspects the process tree. Bash process of the jupyter terminal is child of the jupyter process. Is it a caues?

Comment: I find a solution. I should fix the limit of a jupyter process by using 'prlimit'.